# how do doctored image exploits for image viewers work? can they be defeated with managed code and random pixel alterations?

Tags: browser, exploit, image-formats

I have read that some image viewers were hacked by appropriately doctored images (in a format particularly suited for that? not sure about the details).

So, how could this threat be completely eliminated? For instance, suppose we make a viewer for the affected format written in managed code and have it convert images to a pure BMP (or something else so simple that its viewers cannot be hacked); would the problem go away? How about first convert to BMP and then introduce some pervasive minor random pixel alterations to better disrupt the possible hack?

Let's say this image sanitization converter would be incorporated into the firewall so that only "safe" sanitized images would, by default, end up loaded during regular browsing. Would this solve the problem? Or is my reasoning incorrect due to flawed understanding of the nature of image based exploits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question, i think, boils down to whether the attack lives in the *data* or in the *image*. If it's in the data, then merely decoding the image and re-encoding with a known-good encoder it will ensure safety. If it's in the image, then you may need to alter the pixels.

The famous example of this was [mishandling of JPEG comment fields with bad lengths](http://www.openwall.com/articles/JPEG-COM-Marker-Vulnerability), originally a bug in Netscape, but later independently introduced into [Windows](http://www.unital.com/research/ms_jpeg.pdf). This was very much a data rather than an image problem; the part of the data in question isn't even image data, it's metadata. If you decoded the image with a sandboxed decoder, perhaps detecting and recovering from the corrupt comment field, then re-encoded it with a friendly encoder, the result would be safe even for vulnerable decoders. Doing this naively would lead to a loss of quality; it is possible to losslessly transcode JPEGs, but it requires code to specifically do so.

My gut feeling is that image-level attacks are not possible, only data-level attacks. Image formats are well-enough specified, and fundamentally simple enough, that the content of the image really shouldn't affect the decoding process. I certainly can't prove that, though, nor really even argue for it.